How to securely store and use user passwords in a backup script?
I am setting up an automated backup system for my hosted mailboxes. A script running on a local Windows Server will connect to my hosting platform's IMAP server daily and download each users mail to MBOX files.
I found a Python-based tool which can do this, including only downloading changes rather than the whole mailbox each time. These MBOX files will be archived for 30 days before being overwritten.
I am thinking of writing a script which will call this tool (imap_backup, Github) automatically, once for each mailbox, from a list of mailboxes / users. This will work fine, however it needs each users password to login to the IMAP server. I, as the admin, do have access to these passwords, however I am unsure about the most secure way of handling them / letting the script use them.
All passwords are stored in an encrypted file [Keepass], of course. I am reluctant to have them all sitting plain-text in the file with the list of all mailboxes, but I can't think of a better way.
Would appreciate any suggestions, can provide clarification as needed.
P.S: Backup script will be running on a Windows machine.

In principle, secure secret storage systems with speciality APIs exist, for example, Hashicorp Vault. The idea is that you store only the credentials to the vault in the script, which can also be rotated on demand or regularly and automatically, and also if intrusion is suspected you seal the vault (even automatically by the IDS) so the access to the vault contents (IMAP passwords, etc.) won't be given until human operator(s) manual interference to unseal it back.

I, as the admin, do have access to these passwords - you shouldn't, that's the first problem.

@GeraldSchneider - Well, A) they are secured properly in storage and B) if I didn't have the passwords, I could login to the hosting control panel and reset the passwords to whatever I wanted anyway, so me having access to the account is not really an issue here?

I am reluctant to have them all sitting plain-text in the file with the list of all mailboxes, but I can't think of a better way. Google how to setup local Hashicorp Vault.

@M_D it is. Changing will leave an audit trail. Second, why this convoluted way of performing backups? Why not do it server side?

Should have made it more clear: These mailboxes are hosted on a 3rd party hosting companies mail servers. I have no direct access to the mail servers.

These mailboxes are hosted on a 3rd party hosting companies mail servers. That don't have backup restore capability. There must be 10 better ways of doing email than this in 2025.

For services where data or the service itself could disappear and not be recovered, it is usually a good idea for clients to pull all of the email to their client and not leave email on the ephemeral server behind the web hosting control panel.

@GregAskew - The mail hosting company does have a backup feature. However, as far as I know, their backups are held on their servers (Hopefully different ones to the primary mail server, but still their servers), which is fine, but we recently had a situation where a provider terminated our hosting plan, leaving us with no access. If this happened again with the current provider, we would also lose access to our backups made with their system. Also, clients do hold mail locally to an extent, but it is a lot easier to manage the backups centrally rather than relying on peoples client setups.
